# How can i escape characters from mustache to display the url from a backbone collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I want to use this url to make a api call to render a list:

```
/account/{{#principal}}{{#account}}{{id}}{{/account}}{{/principal}}
```

How can i use this url to call from the backbone collection? I'm looking for escaping the mustache characters or accessing it via a variable.
Something like below:

```
var SubAccountCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

url: '/account/{{#principal}}{{#account}}{{id}}{{/account}}{{/principal}}'
});
```

any ideas on how can i achieve this?

Comment: well from this: '{{#principal}}{{#account}}{{id}}{{/account}}{{/principal}}' I'm getting an account id (ex: accountId: 1234567). so the url technically is: /account/1234566..how can i use this url? as a function or may be a stored variable?

Comment: i doubt if i can use this way as js cannot load the mustache :              url: function(){ return {{#principal}}{{#account}}{{id}}{{/account}}{{/principal}}}

Comment: i tried something like this in my mustache file: <input type ="text" value = "{{#principal}}{{#account}}{{id}}{{/account}}{{/principal}}"/> and it gave me the account id: 123456. I'm wondering how to pass this value into the url to get the id ?

Comment: I get the id from the api call i want to make in order to get the list of sub-list depending on the 'id' i list                 "items": [ {  "name": "abc inc",
                "id": "3e55979f",}]                                    This is the way i get the "id" and "principle" and "accounts" are the attributes defined.

Comment: well im not sure how to pass the {{id}} as a parameter or a variable to get the value. and I need to pass the {{#principal}}{{#account}}{{id}}{{/account}}{{/principal}}} in order to retrieve the id of the list.i tried using the url: function() { return {{#principal}}{{#account}}{{id}}{{/account}}{{/principal}}} } -> gives invalid character..i know im doing something wrong, or may be i need a workaround to get the list 'id'

Comment: 'id' comes from here: "items": [ { "name": "abc inc", "id": "3e55979f",}]. i know i cant use mustache in js, but im sure how to workaround this issue.